# How do I hide the stack trace from my tests

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, create-react-app

every test I run produces 10 pages of pointless node-module stack traces.  How do I get rid of them?  I don't see this in the youtube testing videos, but I haven't found an answer after weeks.

Comment: if you see a stack trace it usually means the code has crashed and the test runner catches this and tries the next test, so limit the test to 1 test and find the problem in your test code. Do all the tests pass?

Comment: Once I cleaned everything up it seems the dom was sending warnings about several unnecessary label properties.

Comment: so it had nothing to do with the node-modules

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to just mock the `console.log` (or any `console`'s method) out. Don't forget to keep the reference to the original method if you plan to restore it back for some other tests.

```js
/** irreversible version */
console.log = jest.fn();

/** reversible version */
const logRef = console.log;

console.log = jest.fn();

// restore when needed
console.log = logRef;
```

Comment: why would a released node module output time consuming log statements, and in particular stack traces

Comment: @rioV8 DB logs transaction data, or Nest logs things about its start-up, or something logs errors that are expected, or anything really?

Comment: @rioV8 particularly, say you test a module that is supposed to throw on some invalid data but this module logs errors to `console.log` locally instead of logging them to an error reporting service in development

Comment: I had to mock console.error instead of console.log.  I didn't know console.error was a thing.  but the answer worked after that and possibly a vscode update.  Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596915/jest-mocking-console-error-tests-fails  Thanks igor